# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Not Allowed in python 3.X how to get rid of bot detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm completely new to coding. I'm trying to create a program to collect data for me however when I code it to open the url, it says HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Not Allowed I'm using Python, I installed Beautiful Soup but for some reason I get this error? i have tried different headers but did not work. Here's the coding below.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re
import numpy as np
# Opening the Builder website

html = "http://www.builderonline.com"
req = urllib.request.Request(html,headers={'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(req).read(),"html.parser")
print ("end")


Error Messages:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 9, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(req).read(),"html.parser")
  File "/Users/NAGS/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/NAGS/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Users/NAGS/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Users/NAGS/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Users/NAGS/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/NAGS/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Not Allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

This page has Captcha and users without JavaScript-prevention. Try this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
request_page = requests.get('http://www.builderonline.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(request_page.text, 'lxml')


for i in soup.findAll('li'):
    print(i.text)
```

If you want to Scrape/Get data from the website I'd suggest using **Selenium** with **PhantomJS** *(headless browser)*.

As for the Error 405:

1. Open an IP socket connection to that IP address.
2. Write an HTTP data stream through that socket.
3. Receive an HTTP data stream back from the Web server in response.
   This data stream contains status codes whose values are determined by the HTTP protocol.

> This error occurs in the final step above when the client receives an
>   HTTP status code that it recognises as '405'.

### Awesome Tutorial [HERE](https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/)

Comment: I have tried your code. It did not work, I have also tried selenium with phantomjs browser but it is asking for recaptcha as it is detecting me as a bot. can you suggest me another way. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using **requests** and **BeautifulSoup** I was able to scrape the **list** tags pretty easily:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from pprint import pprint #for readability
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"}
>>> response = requests.get('http://www.builderonline.com', headers=headers)
>>> soup = BS(response.text, 'lxml')
```

and the output (using `pprint`):

```
>>> for i in soup.find_all('li'):
...     pprint(i)
... 
<li><a class="fa fa-facebook" data-cms-ai="0" href="https://www.facebook.com/buildermagazine" target="_blank" title="Find Us on Facebook"><span class="alt">Facebook</span></a></li>
<li><a class="fa fa-twitter" data-cms-ai="0" href="https://twitter.com/builderonline" target="_blank" title="Find Us on Twitter"><span class="alt">Twitter</span></a></li>
<li><a class="fa fa-linkedin" data-cms-ai="0" href="https://www.linkedin.com/groupInvitation?gid=1296527&amp;fromEmail=&amp;ut=06MzMrJ-ugcmo1" target="_blank" title="Find Us on LinkedIn"><span class="alt">LinkedIn</span></a></li>
<li><a class="fa fa-pinterest" data-cms-ai="0" href="https://www.pinterest.com/builderonline/" target="_blank" title="Find Us on Pinterest"><span class="alt">Pinterest</span></a></li>
<li class="" id="design">
<a data-cms-ai="0" href="http://www.builderonline.com/Design/">Design</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
<ul>
<li>
<a data-cms-ai="0" href="http://www.builderonline.com/design/kitchens/">Kitchens</a>
</li>
<li>
<a data-cms-ai="0" href="http://www.builderonline.com/design/baths/">Baths</a>
</li>
<li>
<a data-cms-ai="0" href="http://www.builderonline.com/project-gallery/">Project Gallery</a><span id="cxssebrfzwttbwxusrsud"><a href="eetaayuducztrwztfvtywwescfzddfuybdaxca.html" rel="file" style="display: none;">fxwyvuwtwuaftsd</a></span>
</li>
<li>
<a data-cms-ai="0" href="http://www.builderonline.com/design/projects/">Projects</a>
</li>
<li>
<a data-cms-ai="0" href="http://www.builderonline.com/design/plans/">Plans</a><a href="eetaayuducztrwztfvtywwescfzddfuybdaxca.html" id="cxssebrfzwttbwxusrsud" rel="file" style="display: none;">fxwyvuwtwuaftsd</a>
</li>
<li>
<a data-cms-ai="0" href="http://www.builderonline.com/design/details/">Details</a><span id="cxssebrfzwttbwxusrsud"><a href="eetaayuducztrwztfvtywwescfzddfuybdaxca.html" rel="file" style="display: none;">fxwyvuwtwuaftsd</a></span>
</li>
```

Maybe it has something to do with the way your header is formatted. Perhaps the site is set to check for malformed or incomplete headers. Try going to https://httpbin.org/headers with your browser and use the **user-agent** data that is listed there in your script.